# Teradata not accepting formatting

Tags: sql, formatting, teradata

I have just started with Teradata. I'm using Teradata Studio Express 17.00.12.00.202012260107, on Windows 10 1909. Formatting appears not to be working at all. The test code:

`SELECT  'ABCDE' (FORMAT 'XXX') AS Shorter ,121.53 (FORMAT '99999') AS Fmt_121 ,121.53 ,991001(date) (FORMAT 'MM/dd/Yy') AS Fmt_NumDate ,991001(date) (FORMAT 'mmmbdd,byyyy') AS Fmt_Date`

Run it in "SQL Editor" window, but output is not formatted at all:

[image]

It should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FORMAT is quite old, it was implemented for importing and reports in BTEQ. In BTEQ/CLI it's applied only before returning data in report format, other clients ignore it.

You can either explicitly cast to a string, or implicitly using:

```
SELECT  trim('ABCDE' (FORMAT 'XXX')) AS Shorter
  ,trim(121.53 (FORMAT '99999')) AS Fmt_121
  ,121.53
  ,trim(991001(date) (FORMAT 'MM/dd/Yy')) AS Fmt_NumDate
  ,trim(991001(date) (FORMAT 'mmmbdd,byyyy')) AS Fmt_Date
```

But I prefer TO_CHAR for numeric and datetime:

```
SELECT substring('ABCDE' from 1 for 3) AS Shorter
  ,to_char(121.53, '09999') AS Fmt_121
  ,121.53
  ,to_char(date '1999-10-01', 'MM/dd/Yy') AS Fmt_NumDate
  ,to_char(date '1999-10-01', 'MON dd, yyyy') AS Fmt_Date
```

I also added the recommended way to write a date, as a *date literal*

Comment: OK. I got this, but how to apply it to specific column?

Comment: See the manuals for more examples: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Ri8d7iL59tIPr1FZNKPLMw/NKA5eaXnCzyexlcxgQzuBg

Comment: Yes, but I already have a column that is timestamp, date or time, just can't figure out how to format them.